# Parse Test Data from Yaml file into Object

Tags: java, json, spring, yaml

I have the following Yaml file of test data:

```
  SEARCH_CREDENTIALS_TEST:
  testName: FB_0001
  nttProductName: TESTNTT
  tpanProductName: TESTTPAN
  userProfile: USERPROFILE
  credentialType: E_COMMERCE_SHORT_FORM_DYNAMIC
  tsp: AETS
  scProfile: Internal
  otherCredentialTypes:
    - E_COMMERCE_LONG_FORM
  maxCachedCredentials: 2
  metadata:
    - HASHED=CUSTOMER_EMAIL
    - UNHASHED=MERCHANT_ID|AMOUNT
  secondRequestMedata:
    - HASHED=CUSTOMER_EMAIL|CUSTOMER_PHONE
    - UNHASHED=MERCHANT_ID|AMOUNT
  restriction:
    fundinglimit:
      -CURRENCY=USD
      -VALUE=10.00
```

I want to store the **funding limit** values of currency and value as properties of a Money object where the amount and currency are stored as string:

```
Money m = new Money();
m.setAmount((String)testData.get("restriction"));
m.setCurrency();
```

How do I get each part of the funding limit object into the money object? My full code snippet is below:

```
@Test(dataProvider = "NetworkTokens", groups = { "p0", "p1", "p2", "p3" })
    public void searchCredentialTest(LinkedHashMap testData) throws Exception {
        
        String credentialType = (String) testData.get("credentialType");


        User user = userUtil.createUser((String) testData.get("userProfile"));
        SecurityContext securityContext = securityContextUtil.createSecurityContext("Default", user);
        Token ntt = createOnlineToken.createNtt(user, securityContext, (String) testData.get("nttProductName"),(String) testData.get("testname"));


        Money m = new Money();
        m.setAmount((String)testData.get("restriction"));
            m.setCurrency(String) testData.get("restriction");
}
```

Here is the postman request for reference of the JSON object I am replicating in my test where I want to get the currency code and value:

```
 {
    "product_name":"TEST_PRODUCT",
    "value_to_tokenize":"TEST_VALUE",
    "wallet_id": "TEST_WALLET",
    "restriction" : {
        "funding_limit" : {"currency_code" : "USD", "value" : "10.00"}
    }
}
```

Comment: have you looked at this one `https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-yaml`

Comment: @Popeye I don't think that would help because I should be able to get the data from the way the test does it for other fields, just need to parse through the nested yaml objects. And the test data is in the form of a linked hash map

Comment: There are also multiple classes used in this overall JSON request

Comment: `Double value = JsonParser.parseString(s).getAsJsonObject().get("restriction").getAsJsonObject()
                .get("funding_limit").getAsJsonObject().get("value").getAsDouble();`